# Trying to save data in UserDefaults and show them in list view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, userdefaults

Trying to save some data in UserDefaults but I'm getting nil in the view.
I don't know where is the problem

This is my code in ContentView:

```
var saveButton: some View {
    Button("Save Meal") {
        let meal = Meal(name: self.mealGenerator.currentMeal!.name,
                        imageUrlString: self.mealGenerator.currentMeal!.imageUrlString,
                        ingredients: self.mealGenerator.currentMeal!.ingredients,
                        instructions: self.mealGenerator.currentMeal!.instructions,
                        area: self.mealGenerator.currentMeal!.area,
                        category: self.mealGenerator.currentMeal!.category)
        self.savedMeals.meals.append(meal)
        self.savedMeals.saveMeals()
    }
```

This is my class I'm trying to save:

```
class SavedMeals: ObservableObject {
    @Published var meals: [Meal]

    func saveMeals() {
        if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(meals) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "Meals")
        }
     }
    
     init() {
        if let meals = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "Meals") {
            if let decoded = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Meal].self, from: meals) {
                self.meals = decoded
                return
            }
        }
        self.meals = []
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to list in a view:

```
struct SavedMealsView: View {

    @ObservedObject var savedMeals: SavedMeals

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(savedMeals.meals) { meal in
                Text(meal.name)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Saved Meals", displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: You are `try?`ing too much. Catch and handle possible errors.

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69148980/trouble-implementing-userdefaults/69154210#69154210) this might help a little

Comment: Why do you have `self.meals = []` at the end of your init?. That should be in an else or you will always end up with an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do `meals = []` at the end of your init regardless of what you decode. Perhaps this will work better:

```swift
init() {
    if data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "Meals") {
        do {
            meals = try JSONDecoder().decode([Meal].self, from: meals)
        } catch {
            assertionFailure("Oops!")
            meals = [] 
        }
    } else {
        meals = []
    }
}
```