# Not understanding timing of UserDefault .set

Tags: swift

I have the following code that looks to have a textfield with the current UserDefault value by the way of the getSongs() function but then on save, update and set the UserDefault to the updated text with the updateLyrics() function as seen below.

```
     var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(getSongs(), id: \.id) { song in
                    Button(action: {
                        self.selectedSong = song
                        self.lyricsText = song.lyrics
                        self.isEditingLyrics = true
                    }) {
                        HStack {
                            Text(song.title)
                            Spacer()
                            Text(song.artist)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isEditingLyrics) {
                VStack {
                    TextField("Lyrics", text: self.$lyricsText)
                    Button("Save", action: {
                        if let selectedSong = self.selectedSong {
                            self.updateLyrics(song: selectedSong)
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func getSongs() -> [Song] {
    let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.lyric_group")

    return try! JSONDecoder().decode([Song].self, from: defaults?.data(forKey: "songs") ?? Data())
   }

func updateLyrics(song: Song) {
        let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.lyric_group")

        if var songs = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Song].self, from: defaults?.data(forKey: "songs") ?? Data()) {
            for index in 0..<songs.count {
                if songs[index].id == song.id {
                    songs[index].lyrics = self.lyricsText
                }
            }

            let encoder = JSONEncoder()
            if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(songs) {
                defaults?.set(encoded, forKey: "songs")
            }
        }

        self.isEditingLyrics = false
    }
```

The odd thing, is that whenever I look at the text after the I update the field with the following code, I have to dismiss the screen then select the same button again for the updated value to appear

Am I missing something obvious with this odd quirk?

Any insight would be appreciated.

I had looked into the .syncronize() but I see that it is deprecated, also it's my understanding that Swift handles this already, so I assume there is just an issue with my implementation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble implementing UserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69148980/trouble-implementing-userdefaults)

Comment: So I admit I am still very new to the intricacies of iOS development with Swift. However, reading that link it did not seem to be similar enough to my issue that it answers my inquiry unfortunately.

Comment: It did mention that I may be leveraging the wrong way to store the data, to which I ask a follow up question:

Because I need to access this data from a custom keyboard extension, could I use something like Firestore/Firebase instead of user defaults? Could the keyboard extension access Firestore data like the main app could?

I just need a way to share data between the main app and the keyboard extension.

Comment: Regarding my original question, just to clarify. I have the data exchange working well. Just odd I have to close and re-open the particular screen to see the updated value. In the main app. Everything updates fine in the keyboard extension.

Comment: Don't understand your keyboard extension thing, but my first thought is that in `ForEach(getSongs(), id: \.id)...`, the UI will not be refreshed by itself. If you were using a `@State var ...` or a `@StateObject var model...`, then the UI would refresh automatically when the var changes.
Have a look at this link, it gives you examples of how to manage data in your app:  
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app  My suggestion is to create a `class SongModel: ObservableObject {}`, put all your functions in there, and use it as 
 described in the link.

Comment: my second thought is that you are correct, you should not be using `UserDefaults` for this data. Firebase works well.

Comment: AppGroups can be used to share data. You need AppStorage if you will continue to use UserDefaults. Your issue will be solved if you implement like the link.

Comment: Ok, I will check out the suggestions. I appreciate the feedback very much so.