# View Updates only one time per view session

Tags: swift, swiftui

When I am tapping the button date all works, but second tap doesn't change anything, only if I reopen my View, then I can press one time, and so on

I have my Habit struct and Model class:

```
struct Habit: Codable, Identifiable, Equatable {
    var id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let description: String
    var streak: Int
    var dateCreated: Date?
    var dateLast: Date?
    
    var dateCreatedString: String {
        dateCreated?.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .omitted) ?? ""
    }
    
    var dateLastString: String {
        dateLast?.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .omitted) ?? ""
    }
}
```

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var habits = [Habit]() {
        didSet {
            if let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(habits) {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "habits")
            }
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "habits") {
            if let loadedData = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Habit].self, from: data) {
                habits = loadedData
                return
            }
        } else {
            habits = []
        }
    }
    
}
```

and my button:

```
Button {
                    if let index = model.habits.firstIndex(where: { $0 == habit }) {
                        model.habits[index].streak += 1
                        model.habits[index].dateLast = Date()
                        habit.dateLast = Date()
                        habit.streak += 1
                        degrees += 360
                    }
                } label: { ... }
```

I tried changing the .firstIndex modifier, and changing Date() with .OnChange - Not working

I expect the user can press the button how many times he wants, without leaving this View

**If I remove lastDate updates this strange behavior is gone**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble implementing UserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69148980/trouble-implementing-userdefaults)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem I suppose

```swift
model.habits[index].dateLast = Date()
habit.dateLast = Date()
```

You are changing habit struct with Date differs from what you put in model's array. So here is two solutions.

```swift
let date = Date()
model.habits[index].dateLast = date
habit.dateLast = date
```

or

```swift
if let index = model.habits.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == habit.id }) {
```

If I were you, I would use them both. Compare ids look more right, or you even use hashmaps.

Comment: $0.id == habit.id works, Thanks a lot!