# UserDefault: Is there any solution to add Favorited Movies into UserDefault

Tags: swift, swiftui, nsuserdefaults

the project is like this, i have a button of adding a movie into Favorited Movies page, and the user can delete the movie (.onDelete). but, the thing here is that whenever i delete the Movie from Favorites, and enter to the same Movie again it shows red button "Remove From Favorites".

furthermore, when i exit the app and try to add another Movie and the earlier Movie is already delete it reappears again above new added Movie.

```
//
//  TrackedMoviesViewModel.swift
//  moviefinder

import Foundation

class TrackedMoviesViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var trackedMovies: [TrackedMovieModel] = []
    
    init() {
            fetchTrackedMovies()
        }
        
    let moviesKey: String = "trackedmovie_list"
    
    
    func addTrackedMovie(_ trackedMovie: TrackedMovieModel) {
        trackedMovies.append(trackedMovie)
        trackMovie()
    }
    
    func isMovieTracked(_ movie: TrackedMovieModel) -> Bool {
            return trackedMovies.contains { $0.id == movie.id }
        }
    
    
    func removeTrackedMovie(_ trackedMovie: TrackedMovieModel) {
        if let index = trackedMovies.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == trackedMovie.id }) {
            trackedMovies.remove(at: index)
            trackMovie()
        }
    }
    
    func deleteMovie(_trackedMovie: TrackedMovieModel){
        //trackedMovies.remove(atOffsets: )
    }
    
    private func trackMovie(){
        if let encodedData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(trackedMovies){
            UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: moviesKey)
        }
    }
    
    func fetchTrackedMovies() {
        if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: moviesKey) {
            if let trackedMovies = try? JSONDecoder().decode([TrackedMovieModel].self, from: data) {
                self.trackedMovies = trackedMovies
            }
        }
    }

}
```

```
//
//  MediaDetailsViewModel.swift
//  moviefinder

import Foundation

class MediaDetailsViewModel: ObservableObject {
@Published var isTracked: Bool = false
var mediaId: Int? // Add this property to store the ID of the media
//var viewModel: TrackedMoviesViewModel

    init(initialIsTracked: Bool, mediaId: Int,trackedMoviesViewModel: TrackedMoviesViewModel) {
        self.isTracked = initialIsTracked
        self.mediaId = mediaId // Set the media ID during initialization
       // self.viewModel = trackedMoviesViewModel
        //updateTrackingStatus()
    }
    
    func toggleTracking() {
        isTracked.toggle()
        updateTrackingStatus(isTracked)
        
    }
    
     func updateTrackingStatus(_ isTracked: Bool) {
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            if let mediaId = mediaId {
                defaults.set(isTracked, forKey: "isTracked_\(mediaId)")
            }
    }
    
    private func loadTrackingStatus() -> Bool {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if let mediaId = mediaId {
            return defaults.bool(forKey: "isTracked_\(mediaId)")
        }
        return false
    }

}
```

This is the button that i have in MovieDetailsView (MediaDetailsView)

```
Button(action: {
                let trackedMovie = TrackedMovieModel(id: details.id, title: details.title, overview: details.overview, poster: details.poster)
                
                if trackedMoviesViewModel.isMovieTracked(trackedMovie) {
                        // Untrack the movie
                        trackedMoviesViewModel.removeTrackedMovie(trackedMovie)
                        } else {
                            // Track the movie
                            trackedMoviesViewModel.addTrackedMovie(trackedMovie)
                        }

                        // Toggle the tracking status
                        mediaDetailsViewModel.toggleTracking()
        
                }) {
                    Text(mediaDetailsViewModel.isTracked ? "Untrack the movie" : "Add to Tracked Movies")
                        .frame(height: 55)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .background(mediaDetailsViewModel.isTracked ? .red : .blue)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                    }
```

Comment: So saving your entities in UserDefaults is not a good idea. UserDefaults prefer to use in any more lightweight cases rather that cache manager. Better to use CoreData/Realm or any other proper service to add/update/delete entities from cache

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble implementing UserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69148980/trouble-implementing-userdefaults)

Comment: Please look at your published items and userdefault updates. Your publishers are called first before you update your datastorage, this maybe the issue you have where it still shows the remove item