onDelete Removing Wrong Entry
I have an array of transaction entries that are sorted by date. Adding and viewing entries works fine, but when deleting an entry, the wrong entry is removed. (No error messages are generated.) I noticed while observing the code with breakpoints and single-stepping that the entry offset used by the sorted array is passed to onDelete instead of the actually stored array offset. Online, I found an example similar to mine using coreData / swiftData, but I couldn't find anything on how to pass the correct offset to onDelete.
Below is my code, including the model and viewModel.
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(WithdrawalModel.self) private var wdvm
    
    let frmt: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy"
        return formatter
    }()
    
    func bankEntries(for date: String) -> [Withdrawal] {
        return wdvm.wdArray.filter { frmt.string(from: $0.wdDate) == date }
    }
    
    // creates a list of unique dates (no duplicates)
    var uniqueDates: [String] {
        Array(Set(wdvm.wdArray.map { frmt.string(from: $0.wdDate) }))
            .sorted { frmt.date(from: $0) ?? Date() < frmt.date(from: $1) ?? Date() }
            .compactMap { $0 }
    }
    
    @State private var rates: Double = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            GeometryReader { g in
                
                VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                    
                    if !wdvm.wdArray.isEmpty {
                        
                        HStack {
                            Text("Time/Location")
                                .padding(.leading, g.size.width * 0.1)
                            
                            Text("Local/Home")
                                .padding(.leading, g.size.width * 0.104)
                        }
                        
                        List {
                            // outer ForEach with unique dates
                            ForEach(uniqueDates, id: \.self) { dateItem in
                                Section {
                                    // inner ForEach with items of this date
                                    ForEach(bankEntries(for: dateItem)) { item in
                                        RowView(item: item)
                                    }
                                } header: {
                                    // display date once for all entries with the same date
                                    Text("\(dateItem)")
                                }
                            }
                            .onDelete(perform: deleteItem)
                        }
                    } else {
                        Text("No Withdrawal Entries")
                            .padding(.top, g.size.height * 0.35)
                    }
                }
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                        Text("ATM Withdrawals")
                            .foregroundStyle(Color.black)
                    }
                    
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        NavigationLink {
                            AddWithdrawalView()
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                                .imageScale(.large)
                                .symbolRenderingMode(.hierarchical)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .toolbarBackground(Color.orange, for: .navigationBar)
                .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
                .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    /*---------------------------------------
     may delete withdrawal entries with swipe left
     ---------------------------------------*/
    func deleteItem(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        
        offsets.forEach { singleOffset in
            wdvm.wdArray.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
            
        }
    }
}

// withdrawal model
struct Withdrawal: Codable, Identifiable {
    
    var id: UUID
    var wdDate: Date        
    var wdCode: String      
    var wdBank: String     
    var wdAmtL: Double  
    var wdAmtH: Double   
    
    init(id: UUID = UUID(), wdDate: Date, wdCode: String, wdBank: String, wdAmtL: Double, wdAmtH: Double) { 
        
        self.id = id
        self.wdDate = wdDate
        self.wdCode = wdCode
        self.wdBank = wdBank
        self.wdAmtL = wdAmtL
        self.wdAmtH = wdAmtH
    }
}

// Withdrawal ViewModel
@Observable final class WithdrawalModel {
    
    var wdArray: [Withdrawal] {
        
        didSet {
            
            // save withdrawal entries
            if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(wdArray) { // save withdrawal entries
                UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: StorageKeys.wdBank.rawValue)
            }
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        
        if let wdArray = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: StorageKeys.wdBank.rawValue) {
            if let decoded = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Withdrawal].self, from: wdArray) {
                self.wdArray = decoded
                return
            }
        }
        
        self.wdArray = []
    }
    
    
    /*---------------------------------------
     save new withdrawal data
     ---------------------------------------*/
    func addNewWithdrawal(wdDate: Date, wdCode: String, wdBank: String, wdAmtL: Double, wdAmtH: Double) -> () {
        
        let item = Withdrawal(wdDate: wdDate, wdCode: wdCode, wdBank: wdBank, wdAmtL: wdAmtL, wdAmtH: wdAmtH)
        
        wdArray.append(item)
        
        if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(wdArray) { 
            UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: StorageKeys.wdBank.rawValue)
        }
    }
}





The array you are deleting from is different to the array you are using to generate the list, so the index passed to delete item will not be correct.

Yes, I know that. I want some info on accessing the correct data.

You can't pass the "correct" index. You can only used the received index to identify the correct object in the source array and then delete that element. In general it is better to not rely on computed properties. You need to update your model so that it exposes the correct arrays rather than computing them in your view.

Can you show a possible solution?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69148980/trouble-implementing-userdefaults/69154210#69154210

lorem ipsum: I don't see how this example has anything to do with deleting entries in a sorted array. I want to sort my entries by date and be able to delete selected entries.

you could try this simple approach as shown in the example code:
func deleteItem(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    offsets.forEach { singleOffset in
        // get the item string from the uniqueDates
        let theItem = uniqueDates[singleOffset]
        // the item as a Date
        if let theItemDate = frmt.date(from: theItem) {
            // get the index of theItemDate from the wdvm.wdArray, and remove it
            if let ndx = wdvm.wdArray.firstIndex(where: {
                Calendar.current.isDate($0.wdDate, inSameDayAs: theItemDate)} ) {
                wdvm.wdArray.remove(at: ndx)
            }
        }
    }
}


I'm getting an error at line "if let ndx"   Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Withdrawal'.  theItem also has the wrong date.

What I presented is an approach, you have to adjust the code for your purpose.
That is, find the equivalent
of theItem in your wdvm.wdArray. So find the entry in
wdvm.wdArray that has wdDate == theItem.
Something like: if let ndx = temp.firstIndex(where: { $0.wdDate == theItem} ) {  wdvm.wdArray.remove(at: ndx) }

Updated the answer, with comparing Dates based on the same day.
